# Spring Integration: Error by using subFlowMapping: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'true'

Tags: spring-integration

I have got this error in my 'normal' code and was able to reproduce it in one simple junit test. 
This error is thrown by using `.route(...)..subFlowMapping(...)`
If I comment `.route(..)` code out then test runs successful.

Could please someone explain why does Spring Integration try to find 'true' channel instead to route to true subflow?

```
@Test
public void testDynaSubFlowCreation() {
    Flux<Message<?>> messageFlux = Flux.just("1,2,3,4").map(v -> v.split(",")).flatMapIterable(Arrays::asList)
            .map(Integer::parseInt).map(GenericMessage<Integer>::new);

    QueueChannel resultChannel = new QueueChannel();

    IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(messageFlux)
            .<Integer, Boolean>route(p->p % 2 == 0, m->m
                    .subFlowMapping(true, sf-> sf.<Integer, String>transform(em->{return "even:"+em;}).log())
                    .subFlowMapping(false, sf-> sf.<Integer, String>transform(em->{return "odd:"+em;}).log())
                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow()
                    )
            .log(l -> "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! end int="+l)
            .channel(resultChannel)
            .get();

    this.flowContext.registration(integrationFlow).register();

    int queueSize = resultChannel.getQueueSize();
    assertThat(queueSize).as("queueSize").isEqualTo(4);
}
```

---

```
2018-02-21 17:33:27,541 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
2018-02-21 17:33:28,184 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'false'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'false' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'false' available, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={id=684db1df-ee6e-f35e-8332-168cee2a1681, timestamp=1519230808175}], headers={id=621649c0-b8a0-4573-9220-c38891544043, timestamp=1519230808181}]
2018-02-21 17:33:28,188 [main] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'false'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'false' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'false' available, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={id=684db1df-ee6e-f35e-8332-168cee2a1681, timestamp=1519230808175}]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannelFromString(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:296)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.determineTargetChannels(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:165)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$1.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$1.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BaseSubscriber.onNext(BaseSubscriber.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.onNext(FluxRetry.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.drain(FluxPublish.java:457)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.onNext(FluxPublish.java:263)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$IgnoreSink.next(FluxCreate.java:571)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.doSend(FluxMessageChannel.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:438)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:388)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.poll(FluxPeekFuseable.java:310)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.drain(FluxPublish.java:411)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PublishSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPublish.java:224)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFlattenIterable.java:206)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable.subscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable.subscribe(FluxFlattenIterable.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable.subscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable.subscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable.subscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable.subscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish.connect(FluxPublish.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.ConnectableFlux.connect(ConnectableFlux.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4707)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.subscribe(FluxMessageChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer.doStart(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.start(ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.java:349)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow.start(StandardIntegrationFlow.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowRegistration.start(IntegrationFlowRegistration.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowContext.register(IntegrationFlowContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowContext.access$500(IntegrationFlowContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowContext$IntegrationFlowRegistrationBuilder.register(IntegrationFlowContext.java:238)
    at com.lr.m3integration.DynaFlowTests.testDynaSubFlowCreation(DynaFlowTests.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'false' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'false' available
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:117)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:223)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'false' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89)
    ... 82 more
```

@artem-bilan:
I'm not completely sure that dynamically registration is a root of a problem.
I configured the same flow statically, like this:

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class IntegrationTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel resultChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public Flux<Message<?>> messageFlux(){
        return Flux.just("1,2,3,4").map(v -> v.split(",")).flatMapIterable(Arrays::asList)
                .map(Integer::parseInt).map(GenericMessage<Integer>::new);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow withSubFlows() {
        return IntegrationFlows
//              .from(inputChannel())
                .from(messageFlux())
                .<Integer, Boolean>route(p->p % 2 == 0, m->m
                        .subFlowMapping(true, sf-> sf.<Integer, String>transform(em->{return "even:"+em;}).log().bridge())
                        .subFlowMapping(false, sf-> sf.<Integer, String>transform(em->{return "odd:"+em;}).log().bridge())
                        .defaultOutputToParentFlow()
                        )
                .log(l -> "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! end int="+l)
                .channel(resultChannel())
                .get();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringIntegrationTest
@SpringBootTest
    @Autowired
    public QueueChannel resultChannel;

    @Autowired
    public MessageChannel inputChannel;

    @Test
    public void testSubFlowCreation() {
        // fill input channel
        IntStream.range(0,4).forEach(i-> inputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(i).build()));

        // receive results after flow processing
        assertThat(resultChannel.getReceiveCount()).as("receiveCount").isEqualTo(0);
        assertThat(resultChannel.receive(1000)).as("message").isNotNull();
        assertThat(resultChannel.getQueueSize()).as("queueSize").isEqualTo(3);
    }
}
```

By executing with input=messageFlux() you will get the same error.
By executing with input=inputChannel() junit test runs green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed. This is a bug in the `RouterSpec`. We can't use `subFlowMapping()` for dynamically registered flows for now. Just because the logic there is based on the `ContextRefreshedEvent`, which happens only once in the application context startup: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4411